# Non-conjugate matrices having the same minimal & characteristic polynomials & the same dimension of the eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

> What is the smallest value of $n$ for which there are two non-conjugate $n\times n$ matrices which have the same minimal and characteristic polynomials and eigenspaces of equal dimension?

I first thought that the answer would be 4, as we know that for $n<4$ having the same minimal and characteristic polynomial implies similarity, but since we have the additional condition that they must have eigenspaces of equal dimension, I am not sure.

Comment: $7.\phantom{           }$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.

Facts: Let $M$ be a matrix with coefficients in $k$. Then $M$ is conjugate to a block-diagonal matrix where each block is a [Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_block). These blocks, up to reordering, classify the conjugacy classes.
Moreover, let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $M$.
Then

- the number of Jordan blocks corresponding to $\lambda$ is the dimension of the eigenspace;
- the size of the largest block corresponding to $\lambda$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda$ in the minimal polynomial;
- the sum of the sizes of the blocks corresponding to $\lambda$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda$ in the characteristic polynomial.

Therefore, it is enough to look for the smallest integer $N$ such that there are an integer $k$, and two different $k$-tuples of integers $(n_1,\cdots,n_k)$ and $(m_1,\cdots,m_k)$ such that:

- $n_1\geq \cdots \geq n_k \geq 1$ and $m_1\geq \cdots \geq m_k \geq 1$;
- $\sum^k_{i=1} n_i = \sum^k_{i=1} m_i = N$;
- $n_1 = m_1$;

and to form two matrices with only one eigenvalue having Jordan blocks of sizes $(n_1,\cdots,n_k)$ and $(m_1,\cdots,m_k)$.

It is easily seen that the smallest $N$ is $7$, and that examples of tuples are $(3,3,1)$ and $(3,2,2)$.

An example of a couple of two matrices is the following:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and

$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: What if the field is not algebraically closed?

Comment: Eh, I guess it makes no difference...

Comment: The minimal polynomial might be irreducible to linear factors so have no Jordan decomposition at all.

Comment: What I wanted to say is: even if the field isn't algebraically closed, the two matrices remain non-conjugate but still have same characteristic and minimal polynomials.

Comment: So $N=7$ still works, but could there be two non-conjugate matrices which have the same irreducible polynomials and eigenspace dimensions, for $N < 7$ ?

Comment: Oh yes. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Hum, I thought I had an argument, but when trying to write it, it did not work...